# Regularization versus feature reduction in species distribution modeling using Maxent

Tags: machine-learning, biostatistics, maximum-entropy

I am wondering if there is a need to set the beta multiplier in Maxent (species distriubition modeling approach) if one is also reducing features using a contribution threshold. I have seen a number of published SDM papers that reduce the number of features, and I have seen others that combine feature reduction with a beta multiplier that is not the default.

I am using AUC to evaluate the models. In addition, I am using K fold validation to estimate a testing AUC. I am comparing the two AUCs to check for model overfitting.

My understanding of using a beta multiplier is basically to provide a "smoother" to compensate for the possibility of model overfitting. If I am removing features, do I also need to identify the "best" beta multiplier? If so, do I need to do this iteratively (i.e. at every subset of the original full feature dataset)?

Answer (score 0):

1) I suggest to NOT use threshold features as is the default in the recent version. I discourage product features, too. -- unless all potential interactions would make sense biologically/ecologically.

2) I suggest to leave the regularization as it is. Not much to gain and how to ecologically interpret any such changes?

3) I suggest NOT to rely on AUC only. Use a number of metrics such as AUC (train or test?), TSS, ORSS ([Stephenson 2000](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/Research/cag-old/publications/2000/wf2000.pdf)), and others. Also think carefully about  what thresholds you use to discriminate yes/no.

4) I suggest using a large number of bootstraps or a small k cross-validation.